# I'm finding difficult to understand deduction theorem with inference rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm finding difficult to understand deduction theorem with inference rules. Now i'm stuck with this question because of lack of understanding in that theorem.

The problem

[image]

```
   1. p=>q      Premise
   2. r=>s      Premise
   3. q∨s => t  Premise
   4. ¬t        Premise
   5. p         Assumption
   6. ....       ......
   7. ....       ......
   8. ....       ......
   9. ¬p         From 4 and 8, ¬_I(Reductio ad absurdum)(Contradiction of line 
                 8 with line 4)

  10. r           Assumption
  11. ....        .....
  12. ....        .....
  13. ....        .....
  14.  ¬r          From 4 and 13, ¬_I(Reductio ad absurdum)(Contradiction of 
                   line 13 with line 4)                
  15.  ¬p∧¬r       From 9 and 14, ∧_I
```

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Max formatting done

Comment: What do you get from 5 and 1?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi i' think it assumes to be true

Comment: I meant, "what do you derive from $p$ (line 5) and $p \Rightarrow q$ (line 1)?"  If you prefer, "what do you deduce from $p \Rightarrow q$ if you assume $p$?"

Comment: hmmm that's the problem that i have :( i have to fill those blanks  @FabioSomenzi

Comment: Take it one step at a time.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi i can assume that because p to be true, then at 6 th step q is true from _E Modus Ponens, after that i cannot figure out what will happen :(

Comment: Good. That's your step 6.  Now, can you deduce $q \vee s$ from $q$?

Comment: since q is true i can get q∨s from ∨_I addition @FabioSomenzi

Comment: Very well.  You are getting there.  Guess what you can get from $q \vee s$ and one of the premises?  By the way, "premise" and "assumption" are not the same.  Your line 5 should be labeled "assumption."  Assumptions are temporary.  In line 5 you say, "let's see what happens if $p$ is true..." which you can also write, "let's see what I can deduce from the assumption that $p$ is true."  In common speech "assumption" and "premise" are often used interchangeably, but in these proofs they are used to denote different concepts.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi oooh yeah, i have mistakenly written Premise instead of Assumption :D my bad. So now in line 8, i can understand because of negation t, (qvs) becomes false too. So what will be the reason? :/

Comment: In line 8 you write that under the assumption of $p$, you deduce $t$ from $q \vee s$ and line 3, but line 4 says $\neg t$, which contradicts $t$.  As the comment to line 9 explains, reduction ad absurdum can be used to deduce $\neg p$.  In summary, you make an assumption ($p$), deduce a contradiction from it ($t$ contradicts $\neg t$); therefore you reject the assumption (deduce $\neg p$).  Note that the reference to line 13 in the comment to line 9 is a cut and paste error.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi so reason for  8th step `¬(pvs) `  is it, implication and negation? :)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi now i got it :D, thanks for helping. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing steps is that after assuming $p$ you have by $p\Rightarrow q$ that $q$ follows and then $q\lor s$ follows and by $(q\lor s)\Rightarrow t$ follows $t$. Now you have a contradiction because of $\neg t$ so you can conclude $\neg p$ instead.

In similar way you conclude $\neg r$ and $\neg p\land\neg r$ follows.

A problem seem to be is that you're mixing up terminology. The deduction theorem states that you can prove a implication by assuming the premise and proving the consequence and by that is proving that the premise implies the consequence. Or formally:

$$\begin{align}\phi&\vdash \psi\\
&\vdash \phi\Rightarrow \psi\end{align}$$

This is not that central to the problem, instead it's reductio ad absurdum which states that a statement can be proved by assuming it's opposite and proving a contradiction by which you can conclude the statement. Or formally:

$$\begin{align}
\neg\psi&\vdash\phi\\
\neg\psi&\vdash\neg\phi\\
&\vdash\psi
\end{align}$$